# FreeLance: Getting full money but not yet completed whole work as we agreed

Tags: money

I have gotten $150 from my clint side as  i have Completed half of my assigned work but not still complete it because Clint does not onlined after last discussion. Should I use now the whole money or return back to Clint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client has **paid advance for the work**, you are **supposed to complete the work**. If this is kind of work which you can complete without client interaction and can be delivered when he needs/appears, like a web page design or a software code etc, than you should complete the work and deliver whenever possible.

But, if that **work is of a kind which needs client interaction** and without that you cannot proceed, than you should **either wait for client until he becomes available or you can return the advance(deducting the amount to compensate your efforts if you want to) if client is very late**.

Comment: it was $250 project and now I sent back $200 to him and now only have $50 but i think I have done almost $100 work

Comment: fair enough, May Allah accept your Taqwah.

Comment: Ameen Allah is Ever there to help you